# Resolving failing Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having trouble with a Maven dependency in a project exported by Eclipse to Tomcat 8...

I am using javax.mail 1.5 which is provided by the Tomcat installation but another package is including javax.mail 1.4 in the Eclipse export. With both versions on the server, it fails to function correctly.

Any idea how I can get Maven or Eclipse to not export the older javax.mail?

Thanks

pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>myproj</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

Comment: You can [explicitly exclude](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) a package from the requirements of one of the depends, i.e. override the dependency list of an included package.

Comment: I dont see a dependency of  javax.mail 1.4 in your pom. You might want to delete all the jars from your lib and rebuild before export to see if it is a leftover jar issue.

Comment: Paste the output of `mvn dependency:tree` somewhere (and don't forget to erase any sensitive data).